# Add timing information to the comments help page

Tags: feature-request, comments

Would it be possible to add some information about the time restrictions to the comments help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment?

- The amount of time users must wait between:

  - upvoting comments
  - deleting comments
  - flagging comments
  - leaving a comment
- How leaving the page you upvote a comment on and returning to (or reloading) the page, prevents un-upvoting the comment?

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but I don't think all of the information belongs on that privileges page. Users can upvote, delete, and flag comments after reaching 15 reputation, not 50. I would think that restrictions related to these actions, if they were to be included, should be included on the voting/flagging pages, not the comment page. The timing restrictions on leaving a comment make sense on the comments page, though.

Comment: @JohnBensin - Is there a more suitable help page that this information would belong on? I looked for more help on comments, however this was the only page I found.

Comment: I don't know. I just think it makes sense to discuss the restrictions on the page that users are linked to when they get the associated privileges. For example, when you earn 15 rep, you're linked to a page about voting and allowed to vote on comments. Since the voting-on-comments restriction now applies to you, I would (personally) want to know about it when I got 15 rep, not when I got to 50 rep. I'm not sure I'm describing that clearly, though.